# HttpResponse flush first 1024bytes

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to stream a log of an operation, this code reproduce the log part (vb.net):

```
Private Sub StartTask()
    Dim cnt = HttpContext.Current
    cnt.Response.Clear()
    cnt.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
    For i = 0 To 100
        Dim msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Ora i è " & i.ToString() & vbCrLf)
        cnt.Response.OutputStream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length)
        cnt.Response.Flush()
        Thread.Sleep(100)
    Next

    cnt.Response.End()
End Sub
```

In client the page I use XMLHttpRequest to read the data, reading response text continuously, my problem is that the update does not work for the first 1024 bytes, then the update is in realtime.

Someone know how to force the send of the initial bytes before of 1024th ?

Comment: Is this a IE-only issue? As I remember there was some minimum for IE before showing any content. Quick workaround: just send 1024 bytes before your updates

Comment: I tried on Chrome, maybe I can try to send 1024 spaces and in client code skip them...